# Adding titles on Plotly subplots in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am working with Plotly. Below you can see my data and code.

```
# Sample data frame 1
df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Value = c(10, 15, 20, 25)
)

# Sample data frame 2
df2 <- data.frame(
  Category = c("X", "Y", "Z", "W"),
  Value = c(30, 22, 18, 12)
)

# Bar chart for data frame 1
plot1 <- plot_ly(df1, x = ~Category, y = ~Value, type = 'bar', name = 'Data Frame 1') %>%
  layout(title = 'Bar Chart for Data Frame 1', xaxis = list(title = 'Category'), yaxis = list(title = 'Value'))

# Bar chart for data frame 2
plot2 <- plot_ly(df2, x = ~Category, y = ~Value, type = 'bar', name = 'Data Frame 2') %>%
  layout(title = 'Bar Chart for Data Frame 2', xaxis = list(title = 'Category'), yaxis = list(title = 'Value'))
```

Now I want to plot this charts in one facet. Below you can see my code and chart.

```
# Combine the charts into one facet
facet_chart1 <- subplot(plot1, plot2, nrows = 1)
```

[image]

This code produces a facet chart with two sub charts but lacks titles for each of them. Can anybody help me with solving this problem and displaying titles above each chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a look at how facet titles are achieved with `ggplotly()` one option would be to add subplot titles via `add_annotations` like so:

```r
library(plotly)

plot1 <- plot_ly(df1,
  x = ~Category, y = ~Value,
  type = "bar",
  name = "Data Frame 1"
)
plot2 <- plot_ly(df2,
  x = ~Category, y = ~Value,
  type = "bar",
  name = "Data Frame 2"
)

p <- subplot(plot1, plot2,
  nrows = 1,
  shareX = TRUE,
  shareY = TRUE
) |>
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Category"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Value")
  ) |>
  add_annotations(
    x = c(.25, .75),
    y = 1,
    xref = "paper",
    yref = "paper",
    text = c("Bar Chart for Data Frame 1", "Bar Chart for Data Frame 2"),
    showarrow = F,
    xanchor = "center",
    yanchor = "bottom",
    font = list(size = 12)
  )
p
```

[image]